# Nested Editable Listview bound to Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a problem similar to the one found in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994944/how-to-edit-data-in-nested-listview)

I have a ListView nested inside of another listview. The outer Listview is bound to an object in the codebehind.

```
listViewOuter.DataSource = myObject[0].someProperty;
listViewOuter.DataBind();
```

Where someProperty is a List of another object(mySecondObject)...

The inner Listview needs to be editable and it is bound in the markup to another property(secondObjectProperty) of type List in the mySecondObject as such:

```
DataSource='<%# Eval("secondObjectProperty")%>'
```

This works fine to display the data, however I cannot figure out how to put the nested listview into edit mode.  I am handling the OnItemEditing command and setting the EditIndex to the proper row however the mode of the nested LV never changes. I have tried every imaginable combination of updates panels and rebinding both the inner and outer listviews however nothing seems to work

heres the LV markup(psuedocode)

```
<updatePanel>
<asp:ListView ID="outerListView" runat="server">
   <layouttemplate here>

   <itemTemplate>
     <aspListView ID="innerListView" DataSource="<%# Eval("secondObjectPropery")%  onitemEditng="editMethod">


     </asp:LsitView>
   </itemTEmplate>
</asp:ListView>

</updatePanel
```

Any ideas????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a solution. Instead of binding the nested listview in the markup with the "DataSource" tag, I am binding it in the ItemDataBound event of the outer listview.

In this event I check for an editItemIndex that I am storing as a global variable which is set via the nested listviews ItemEditing event. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one of those inside your `<ItemTemplate>`?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        Text="Edit" />
```

Comment: I do have an edit button...which is successfully firing the onitemeiditing event...I found a solution for this that I will post now.